# How do I reuse the sample data across platform in Blend?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, blend

I am starting to design the UI with Blend 2013. There is a sample data I created from the class. I use it in the WP8.1 project. Now, I want to design the WPF project with the same data. I tried to use the solution from

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25551.expression-blend-playing-with-sample-data-wpf-windows-phone.aspx#Re_usability_of_Sample_Data_Generated

But it does not work. I thought because the namespace reference between the the platform are different.

WP8.1 >> xmlns:ViewModels="using:

WPF >> xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:

Then, can anyone suggest me the solution for this case?